# Wget loop bash with download numbering?

Tags: bash, wget

How could i do, something that goes like this:

wget http://website.com/page.html
every x seconds, and number them.
I would like my output to be like this:
page1.html
page2.html
etc

I already know how to do the wget loop with

```
 while true sleep 10; do wget http://website.com/page.html; done
```

, however i'm unsure of numbering. Thanks everyone.

even better would be with date and time in the file name aswell, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with numbering:

```
declare counter=1; while true sleep 10; do wget http://example.com -O page$counter.html; ((counter++)); done
```

Explanation:
`declare counter=1` declares the `counter` variable and sets it to `1`, `-O $counter.html` outputs the result of wget to `page1.html`, `page2.html`, `page3.html` and so on, `((counter++))` increments the variable.

Solution with date and time in filename:

```
while true sleep 10; do wget http://example.com -O "page$(date).html"; done
```

Explanation: `$(date)` returns current datetime.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Simple enough I guess, I would like to learn a bit more bash.